# How to make a generic parent constructor that accepts object with keys of child class?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to make a base class that defines a constructor that allows all the keys of the child class to be passed, but `this` is unavailable in constructors. Here's what I'd like to achieve:

```js
class BaseClass {
  constructor(props: {[key in keyof typeof this]?: typeof this[key]}) {
    Object.assign(this, props)
  }
}

class User extends BaseClass {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const user = new User({name: "John"});
```

But this errors with:

```js
test.ts:2:60 - error TS2333: 'this' cannot be referenced in constructor arguments.

2   constructor(props: { [key in keyof typeof this]?: typeof this[key] }) {
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm not satisfied with any solutions where I have to supply any information about the child classes in the parent class' constructor.

Comment: Without [ms/TS#38038](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38038), you'd need to work around the limitation you're hitting.  The polymorphic `this` type is an implicitly F-bounded generic type parameter; one way to work around is to do it explicitly as shown [in this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mL5YKW).  Does that fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Nice! Thanks for both the GitHub issue and Playground link! Specifying the classname again as a generic isn't that big of a hit! Doable workaround. If you write it up as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, it is currently not allowed to use the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) in constructor parameters.  There is an open feature request for such support at [microsoft/TypeScript#38038](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38038). It's open and marked as "awaiting more feedback", so anyone who is interested in seeing this happen might want to go there, give the issue a , and possibly describe their use case and why it's compelling. The more people do that the more chance there is that it would eventually be implemented, but it's not likely to happen overnight and maybe not ever.  So until and unless that happens, you'll need to work around it.

The polymorphic `this` type acts as an implicitly [F-bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  (What's "F-bounded"? That's just the technical term for saying that it is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to some Funcion of itself.  If you had a generic type parameter `X` and a generic type `type F<T> = ...`, then `X extends F<X>` would mean that `X` is "F-bounded".)  Therefore, in cases where `this` is not allowed, you could try to work around it with an *explicitly* F-bounded generic type parameter, like so:

```
class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass<T>> {
    constructor(props: { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] }) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}
```

or equivalently

```
class BaseClass<T extends BaseClass<T>> {
    constructor(props: Partial<T>) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}
```

using [the `Partial` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype).

That now compiles with no error.  Your subclasses would then need to be declared in terms of themselves:

```
class User extends BaseClass<User> {
    name?: string;
    age?: number;
}
```

Note that I made the `name` and `age` properties [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) because the base class doesn't necessarily set them (it asks for `Partial<T>`).  If it *did*, you'd probably need to use a definite assignment assertion like `name!: string` or a property declaration like `declare age: number`, since the compiler does not understand that `Object.assign()` in the super constructor body will actually initialize the declared properties.  This is mostly a digression, though.

And everything else works as expected:

```
const user = new User({ name: "John" });
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4oB4Aq0EA8AuCAdgCYzwTKoSYB8N0A3gFDSvTAD2hEeATgK7A8HXgAoADrw7iIALmgAFMLzwBLMCFoBKRizb6A8gCMAVgiEA6SBFUBzQqLwALVRAA00SdIhaA3HtYAXyZgplBraABVCl5sfCJSOEQUazRohF56Zn1CMABbBAB+eR5eVUJbf30wWyL5Qn48owz-UM5uPGh+GOgAXmhCBAB3KJjRBgH8hHkAIgApDidCGehAvyA)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using a generic type parameter and the `keyof` keyword in the constructor of the base class.

```js
class BaseClass<T> {
  constructor(props: { [key in keyof T]?: T[key] }) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
}

interface User {
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}

class User extends BaseClass<User> implements User {}

const user = new User({ name: "John" });
```

You can read more about Typescript generics [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

Comment: Good answer! I can't separate my definition into a class and interface because of decorators and don't want to duplicate it, so @jcalz playground answer is more what I'm looking for, and is more concise.

Comment: Make sure you have `useDefineForClassFields` set in `false`, though, because if not, the transpiler will emit ECMAScript standard compliant class fields and all declared properties on the child class will be undefined. This flag is `true` by default if your target is `ES2022` or higher, including `ESNext` :)